# PHP Header, variable (external) link opening as if it were on my server

Tags: php, header

So, pretend I was opening www.example.com, using a `$link` variable and `header()`. Here's my code:

```
header("Location: ".$link);
```

Here's the result: http://reecemcmillin.com/test/www.example.com

How can I just get it to open www.example.com, instead of having it pretend it was a file on my server?

Comment: Is $link http : //www.example.com or just www.example.com? (ignore the spaces, just getting around SO auto-linking)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ensure `$link` includes 'http://':

```
$link = 'http://www.example.com';
```

Comment: $link = substr($strip1, 0, 30);
Leaves the link as the ONLY info on the page.

Comment: Then add the necessary pieces after the fact: `header("Location: http://" . $link`